# How do I disable javascript on webspec?

Tags: java, watij

There is a way to disable javascript on webspec? Like is done,for instance, on htmlunit?

Answer (score 1):

this question was previously asked on the Watij Google Groups.

[Disabling Javascript](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/watij/disable%2420javascript/watij/_t9NerpLHtY/au7SQaT-jtEJ)